# Is a messaging loop required for every window in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

Example loop ([object extended from Shell](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FShell.html) -- using the Window Builder Eclipse addon, even though the docs say not to extend Shell?!?):

```
while(!this.isDisposed())
{
  if(!this.getDisplay().readAndDispatch())
  {
    this.getDisplay().sleep();
  }
}
```

So my top window shell has one of these loops, and then my modal dialog has one of these loops... Is it the intention of SWT that every window should have a loop? The reason I ask, how come this isn't a default "open" behaviour of the Shell class?

Comment: In Eclipse, which is what SWT was developed for, the loops are not required.  They are part of the Eclipse core.  When you use SWT outside of Eclipse, you have to provide a messaging loop for every Display you create.

Comment: That's the issue I'm having. I've only created one display... but when I open my "child" shell (SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL), it closes immediately unless I add another loop. I still only have one display created (for the top window).

Comment: I don't write much stand alone SWT, so I guess you're right.  Messaging loops everywhere you need one.

Comment: Does your `Shell` have a parent, or is it a top-level shell?  Usually your modal dialog would be a `Dialog`, not a `Shell`, and never a top-level shell.

Comment: Nothing fancy... top window uses Display.getDefault() and uses the default new Shell() constructor. The child is passed that shell and uses the Shell constructor that accepts a shell as its parent. I'm looking at the swt controls example and it's not using a messaging loop for every dialog. (I guess I still have a lot more to read!)

Comment: No, you definitely don't need to have more than one messaging loop (unless you have more than one `Display`, which you shouldn't).